# Change body tag class in Angular 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

My problem is I have multiple pages that require a different body class for each page.

So without using `$rootScope` how can I change this in the DOM depending on which page is being displayed?

```
<body class="class-that-needs-changing">
```

Comment: multiple pages meaning separate html files or just different ui routes?

Comment: Just throwing my 2 cents... have you considered ng-class attribute?

Comment: are yo using route to change view?

Answer (score 1):

Let's make use of a directive like this:

```
.directive('bodyClasses', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var classes;

            scope.$watch(function(scope) {
                return scope.$eval(attrs.bodyClasses);
            }, function(value) {
                classes = value;
                angular.element(document.body).addClass(value);
            });

            // Remove body class when scope or directive destroyed.
            scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                angular.element(document.body).removeClass(classes);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Now, use this directive in your separate HTML pages like this:

```
<!-- remember, use single quote for string since we are evaluating it -->
<div body-classes="'new-class another-class'"></div>
```

or

```
<span body-classes="'foo' {{someScopeVariable}}"></div>
```

As a particular page or view will load, those classes will be added to the `body` tag. In this way, you can keep your class separate in each individual page and your main `body` tag will not clutter.

Answer (score 0):

You have two main options:

1. Add a variable to the $rootScope and be done with it. If you only have this one global setting for the body class that needs to be changed I would suggest this as it is easy.
2. Make an angular service that handles global page settings. Inject this service into the controllers that need to have the global page settings and then retrieve the global page settings from the service and bind them to each controller scope. If you have many global settings or need any business logic to happen then use this service approach instead.

Comment: I have always been told never to use $rootScope

Comment: It is considered bad practice. Putting lots of junk in $rootScope will make your app hard to understand as that junk gets inherited into every other scope. On the other hand, making an angular service, injecting it into each controller, and manually wiring up the scopes is a decent amount of work and complicates a simple problem. For a small problem like this one, using $rootScope will be fine. However, if more global configurations per page have to be added, you may want to consider using a service.

Comment: Oh, okay I see your logic. There really isn't much more too it other than changing the class so I think $rootScope is the best option here. Thanks for setting me straight on the correct use case for $rootScope.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your posting, I suggest changing the body class in `angular.Module.run`, this method would register a task which would be executed when angular application fully loaded:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
   .run(['$scope', function($scope){

        var className = 'different-classes';
        angular.element(document.body).addClass(className);

   }]);
```

since your multiple pages are totally different html files, the angular application would be reloaded each time after navigating from one page to another

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an elegant solution here, does there? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: well, it depends on your requirements, if you just need to change body class only once through entire page life cycle, this would be the most easy to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it on app.js

//app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', [
   'ngCookies',
   'ngResource',
   'ngSanitize',
   'ngRoute'
])
.constant('config', {
   user1:'class1',
   user2:'class2'
})
```

// main.js

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MainCtrl', [ '$scope', 'config',
   function ($scope, config) {
       console.log(config.user1);
   }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `$rootScope` you can make a **listener** to detect view change means `$routeChangeSuccess` (I guess you used `$routeProvider` to change view) and you should have a **parent** controller in which you create your **listener**

like:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('parentController', function($scope, $route) {
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if ( newValue !== oldValue ) {
            $scope.bodyClass = $route.current.viewClass;
        }
    });
});
```

and your provider should like:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/list',{
       controller: 'listController',
       templateUrl: '/list.html',
       viewClass:  'class1'
    }).when('/details', {
       controller: 'detailsController',
       templateUrl: '/details.html',
       viewClass:  'class2'
    }).otherwise({
       redirectTo: '/list'
    });
});
```

so your HTML should like:

```
<body ng-controller="parentController" class="commonClasses" ng-class="bodyClass ">
```

Can visit [PLUNKER DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/IoYiV3sQCJPBPH7Lom56?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your solution :) Will I have to use this in my main app.js module or can I break it off into lets say the nav module?

Comment: better to use `parentController` in your main module. :)